# Where is the location for old WhatsApp database?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

In my internal memory, I found the WhatsApp database folder, but it only contains a few files, a maximum of 6/7 days.

Where can I find my old WhatsApp database files? Where would I get the previous days' or months' chat database?

Comment: You can't because it stores only last 7 days worth of backups

Answer (score -1):

if you start what's app without restoring previous data it gets deleted and if you are talking about encryption you can eaisly access it by scanning the qr code in other device

Comment: Thanks for ur replies..Can I , in any way, restore deleted chats which not in the days of internal database dates? Further I have backed up my account with Google drive after the deletion carelessly. When I triedthat deleted part before back up never restored. What can I do?